# Python 3.x Dictionaries

Tags: python, scripting

I want to pull some information from this dictionary, such as usernames.
I can print the dictionary, but how do I pull any data into different variables?

```
import csv
import pprint

csv_reader = csv.DictReader(open('accounts.csv', encoding='utf-8'))
line_count = 0
dict_list = []
for line in csv_reader:
    dict_list.append(line)
pprint.pprint(dict_list)
```

Is there any easier way to do this as I'm pulling username's and passwords from a .csv

I'm very new to Python so sorry if this is a stupid question

Edit: Typos

Comment: You would need to add at least 2 lines from the `accounts.csv` headers and one line of values.

If not, nobody will know how.

Answer (score 1):

So I worked it out myself

```
print(dict_list[1]["key_name"])
```

exactly what I wanted!!